# Error SQL syntax, what this error message means?

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop

> Fatal error: Uncaught You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2 `SELECT * FROM cities WHERE id_city =`  thrown in /home/skygoatm/public_html/classes/db/Db.php on line 635

i have no idea on my prestashop site,
i try back up, then replace the page with original code when i download prestashop earlier version, but nothing happen n still show that error message.
i have done nothing before, never touch or open any code in FTP nor doing somehing with code in hosting.what should  do?

Comment: If you haven't edited the code then it is probably a configuration issue. Are you running the PHP/mysql versions the presta should have? With nothing after the `=`s I'd guess a variable isn't defined, or is defined incorrectly.

Comment: looks like you are assigning an empty value in your query add single quote into it like `id_city = '".$id_city."'`

Comment: please add sql query

Comment: Please add your code also.

Answer (score 0):

This error appears when no value is passed to the Where.
One tip:

- enter a check before the query to see if the variable assigned to the where is full and set